# How to add data in more columns to a row which has already been written in Excel using axlsx in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, axlsx

I am using axlsx to create Excel sheets in Ruby on Rails

Say, I use something like this code to add data to a row

```
some_array.each do |element| #array has a few hundreds of elements
  sheet.add_row [element.dcol1, element.dcol2, element.dcol3] #start from row1 of Excel sheet
  # the above statement would print data into columns A, B & C
end
```

This loop above adds a few hundreds of records to the Excel in 3 columns - `A, B & C`

Now, I would like to add completely different data (say from `some_other_array`); I would like to start printing this array `again from row1` in Excel but from say `column J`

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

`axlsx` allow you to edit any cell in the file without the `add_row` method using `sheet.rows[ROW_NUMBER].cells[NUMBER].value = VALUE`.

To achieve what you want, you can do:

```
some_array.each_with_index do |element, index|
  sheet.rows[index].cells[10] = element.dcol1
  sheet.rows[index].cells[11] = element.dcol2
  sheet.rows[index].cells[12] = element.dcol2
end
```